# HIbernate SELECT query for composite key defined using @IdClass annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

My table VENDORBRANCH has **composite keys**: "vendorCode" and "vendorBranchCode" which I have defined using the @Id annotation and using @IdClass. The field "vendorCode" is referenced as a foreign key in VENDORCRTERMS class. I'm using postgresql db. 
Right now my sql query in the service implimentation looks like this but i want to include composite keys in the query:

```
 Query<?> query = session.createQuery("from VENDORBRANCH where vendorCode = ?");
        query.setParameter(0, mf01_vendorCode);
```

I'm very new to hibernate so tried a few options for the select query but I'm not sure if it's correct to do it this way. So, what would be the best select statement to use for a composite key??

**VENDORBRANCH** class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;    
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import com.parkson.poMain.backend.data.VENDORBRANCH.VBpk;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@IdClass(VBpk.class)
public class VENDORBRANCH implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String vendorCode;

    @Id
    private String vendorBranchCode;

    //getters and setters

    // inner class defined for primary key(composite keys)
    public static class VBpk implements Serializable {
        protected String vendorCode;
        protected String vendorBranchCode;

        public String getvendorCode() {
            return vendorCode;
        }

        public void vendorCode(String vendorCode) {
            this.vendorCode = vendorCode;
        }

        public String vendorBranchCode() {
            return vendorBranchCode;
        }

        public void vendorBranchCode(String vendorBranchCode) {
            this.vendorBranchCode = vendorBranchCode;
        }

        public VBpk(){}

        public VBpk(String vendorCode,String vendorBranchCode){
                this.vendorCode = vendorCode;
                this.vendorBranchCode = vendorBranchCode;
            }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((vendorBranchCode == null) ? 0 : vendorBranchCode.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((vendorCode == null) ? 0 : vendorCode.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            VBpk other = (VBpk) obj;
            if (vendorBranchCode == null) {
                if (other.vendorBranchCode != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!vendorBranchCode.equals(other.vendorBranchCode))
                return false;
            if (vendorCode == null) {
                if (other.vendorCode != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!vendorCode.equals(other.vendorCode))
                return false;
            return true;
        }       
    }
}
```

**My other class: VENDORCRTERMS**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;    
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity  
public class VENDORCRTERMS implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String  vcrId ;

   //This is the foreign key referenced from **VENDORBRANCH class** 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name="vendorbranch_vendorcode", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name="vendorbranch_vendorBranchCode", nullable = false)} )
    private VENDORBRANCH vendorbranch_vendorcode = new VENDORBRANCH();  

    // foreign key referenced from a different class
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "creditterms_credittermscode" , nullable = false)
    private CREDITTERMS creditterms_credittermscode = new CREDITTERMS();

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: You were advised yesterday on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178725/composite-key-join-columns  that your mapping is wrong. If you have MULTIPLE PK columns then a FK reference to that type has to also have MULTIPLE FK columns. You commit the same mistake here. If you aren't going to bother fixing that then I see little point in a further question (if this is indeed something different)

Comment: I have fixed the mapping  problem already thanks to the people who answered it properly. Just missed out on updating that piece of code in this one(which I'm going to do now). This question is about the SQL query and not about the mapping in the entity class if u bother reading my question properly before jumping to conclusions

Comment: well if you have "fixed the mapping problem" then kindly update your question to show the correct (valid) mapping.

Comment: Done. Now if you could kindly be of any help in this regard, I'd be highly obliged. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.Didn't realize earlier.

Comment: your "sql query" is not an SQL query. It is JPQL. It is also invalid JPQL. JPQL should be of the form `SELECT {result} FROM candidate alias WHERE filter`. You have omitted the candidate alias, and the SELECT part. Getting beyond your use of INVALID JPQL, if you want to select based on BOTH Id fields then `... WHERE vendorCode = :param1 AND vendorBranchCode = :param2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composite key join columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178725/composite-key-join-columns)